# Opencart Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerCatalogProduct::$data

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I know it has been asked a ton of times but everywhere I look for a solution, I see nothing but disappointment when testing.

Please Help!

I am making changes to the core Product Controller of opencart version 2.x

I am trying to render a variable in the view file. But I am not able to access it. I get the above mentioned error whenever I try to do it using something like this:

```
$this->data['view'] = array('1','2','3','4');
```

If I do it like this:

```
$data['view'] =  array('1','2','3','4');
```

I cannot access the $view variable in the view file at all.

Please help on this on.

---

update

I am assigning the value in the index method of the Product Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed it. Just in case someone faces same issue below is the solution.

If you don't really need to pass data in the view, opencart engine automatically loads the respective language data, view, common files. You don't have to define it or pull data. That's the reason the above statements don't work.

But in case you need to pass values to the view from the controller then you will need to manually load everything, header,  footer,  language text, etc and then load the view in the controller.

Hope it helps.